# Truncate string according to object map

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have a big list of URL paths which I need to transform. The rules for how to transform each URL are expressed as an object. I.e. for this **input**:

```
const inputUrls = [
    '(entrance)',
    '/Introduction',
    '/about',
    '/car-models',
    '/car-models/ct/',
    '/car-models/ct',
    '/car-models/ct/ct-200h',
    '/',
    '/',
    '/car-models/ls/',
    '/car-models/ls',
    '/car-models/ls/ls-200h',
    'car-config.example.com/',
];
```

coupled with these **rules**:

```
const rules = {
    'about': {},
    'car-models': { 'ct': { 'ct-200h': {} } },
    'car-config.example.com': {}
};
```

The **output** should be:

```
const outputUrls = [
    '(entrance)',
    '/Introduction',
    '/about',
    '/car-models',
    '/car-models/ct',
    '/car-models/ct',
    '/car-models/ct/ct-200h',
    '/',
    '/',
    '/car-models',
    '/car-models',
    '/car-models',
    'car-config.example.com',
];
```

As in: all urls should be transformed to the closest single level directory

```
const rules = {};
transform('/car-models/ct/ct-200h', rules) === '/car-models'
```

*unless* the rules object contains that directory, in which case it should keep another directory level, i.e.

```
const rules = { 'car-models': {} };
transform('/car-models/ct/ct-200h', rules) === '/car-models/ct'
```

I've tried to create the `transform` function in a few different ways. This is what I've got now. I think it's along the right lines but it clearly doesn't work for every case, especially urls that don't contain a `/` at all.

```
function transform(rules = {}, url = '', isInternal = true) {

    if (url === '' || url === '/') {
        return isInternal ? '' : url;
    } else {
        const splitUrl = url.split('/');
        const firstPart = splitUrl[0];
        const nextParts = splitUrl.slice(1);

        if (splitUrl.length < 2) {
            return firstPart;
        } else {
            const branch = rules[firstPart === '' ? splitUrl[1] : firstPart];
            if (branch) {
                const merged = nextParts.join('/');
                return transform(branch, merged);
            } else {
                return url;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've spent a lot of time looking at this so I may not have explained things clearly. Happy to answer questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate the splitted URL and walk the rules. Then slice if a part is found.

```js
var inputUrls = ['(entrance)', '/Introduction', '/about', '/car-models', '/car-models/ct/', '/car-models/ct', '/car-models/ct/ct-200h', '/', '/', '/car-models/ls/', '/car-models/ls', '/car-models/ls/ls-200h', 'car-config.example.com/', 'car-config.example.com/stuff'],
    rules = { 'about': {}, 'car-models': { 'ct': { 'ct-200h': {} } }, 'car-config.example.com': {} },
    outputUrls = inputUrls.map(function (a) {
        var o = rules,
            p = a.split('/'),
            i = +!p[0],        // correction for first slash/empty string
            offset = 1;

        while (p[i] in o) {
            offset = 0;
            o = o[p[i]];
            i++;
        }
        return p.slice(0, i + offset).join('/');
    });

console.log(outputUrls);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for all my urls! The only exception is that I'd like to ideally also remove the `/` at the end of `"car-config.example.com/"`. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. Also I just noticed that `"car-config.example.com/stuff" => "car-config.example.com/stuff`. Since `"car-config.example.com"` isn't in the rules object it shouldn't show any of its subfolders

Comment: Ooh yes it seems to work, thanks! Now I just need to make sense out of your compact code :P

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late to the party. I haven't checked my solution thoroughly, but results fit yours.

```js
function transform(paths, rulesTree) {

  return paths.map((path) => {
  
    let lastRoot = rulesTree;
    const resultTokens = [];
    let ifOnlyBranch = false;
    const inputTokens = path.replace(/(?:^\/|\/$)/g, '').split('/');
    const ifAll = inputTokens.every((pathToken) => {

      resultTokens.push(pathToken);
      ifOnlyBranch = !Object.keys(lastRoot).length;
      lastRoot = lastRoot[pathToken];
      return lastRoot;
    
    });
    let res;
    if (ifAll || ifOnlyBranch) {
      res = resultTokens;
    } else {
      res = resultTokens.slice(0, Math.max(1, resultTokens.length - 1));
    }
    const prefix = path[0] === '/' ? '/' : '';
    return prefix + res.join('/');
  
  });

}

const inputUrls = [
    '(entrance)',
    '/Introduction',
    '/about',
    '/car-models',
    '/car-models/ct/',
    '/car-models/ct',
    '/car-models/ct/ct-200h',
    '/',
    '/',
    '/car-models/ls/',
    '/car-models/ls',
    '/car-models/ls/ls-200h',
    'car-config.example.com/',
];

const rules = {
    'about': {},
    'car-models': { 'ct': { 'ct-200h': {} } },
    'car-config.example.com': {}
};

console.log( transform(inputUrls, rules) );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Your answer seems to work but I'm going to accept Nina's cos her code is a little more compact. Thanks!

Comment: Compact code may be more difficult to read and understand (and so maintain). But it's a matter of preference, of course. Good luck!